# Excel VBA move cursor to end of text in the Excel cell

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel, I have Cell.Range("D7") with certain text that keeps getting updated. I want to `Cell.Range("D7").Select` and move the cursor to end of the text in Cell "D7"

This is what I tried but am getting error `Application-Defined or Object-Defined Error`.

```
 Dim cell As Range
 Set cell = Me.Range("D7")
 If cell.Text <> "" Then
    cell.Select
    cell.End(xlToEndOfText).Select
 End If
```

Comment: Are you expecting some input from the user at the end of the cell? Otherwise just do something like `Cells(7,1).value=str(Cells(7,1).value)+"stuff"` to append at the end of the cell...

Comment: I am trying to build a system where user can type special characters and then double click on certain cells which would cause the value in Cell D7 to get merged with the value of cell doubleclicked on and then move the cursor to the end of the text in D7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Solution by doing some googling

```
' Set focus to the cell and move the cursor to the end of the text
  Dim cell As Range
  Set cell = Me.Range("D7")
   If cell.Text <> "" Then
      cell.Select
      cell.Activate

 ' Move the cursor to the end of the text by sending the combination of keys
  Application.SendKeys "{F2}"
  Application.SendKeys "{END}"
  Application.SendKeys "{RIGHT}"
End If
```

Thank you

Comment: I would call this more like a work-around than a solution. ;-)

Comment: @destructioneer Have been wondering what would call it a Solution?